# Use string as field name in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

Look the code below. I'd like to replace `USERNAME` by the field name received in the parameter `field`. This method must be able to make some search on several fields.

Thank,

```
public void Searching(string field, string stringToSearch)
{
    var res = 
        from user in _dataContext.USERs where 
        user.USERNAME.Contains(stringToSearch)
        select new 
        {
          Id = user.ID,
          Username = user.USERNAME
        };

}
```

Comment: Is it LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Objects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to forget about the anonymous type, maybe use `Tuple<int,string>` instead; but: how about:

```
IQueryable<Foo> source = // YOUR SOURCE HERE
      // in-memory dummy example:
      // source = new[] {
      //    new Foo {Id = 1, Bar = "abc"},
      //    new Foo {Id = 2, Bar = "def"}
      // }.AsQueryable();

string field = "Bar";
string stringToSearch = "d";
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Foo), "x");
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, field),
        "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(stringToSearch)
    ), param);
var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, Tuple<int, string>>>(
    Expression.Call(typeof(Tuple), "Create", new[] {typeof(int), typeof(string)},
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Id"),
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, field)), param);
Tuple<int,string>[] data = source.Where(predicate).Select(projection).ToArray();
```

Comment: Damn, you were faster by a minute... and I didn't have time to test mine. Hope it still works though :)

Comment: So it is possible but is it a good practice for querying different columns ? Shouldn't we divide them Mr.Gravell ? And I really admire your work.

Comment: @RoboLover how do you mean "divide them" ? As a basic "find me some matches; I want the unique-id and the thing-that-matched" it isn't unreasonable

Comment: Kris says `This methode must be able to make some search several field.` If I am not misunderstanding he wants to send a parameter that will be the column name in the query. For example, USERNAME, CELLPHONE, ADDRESS. What I am asking is shouldn't this be done with three different queries but not with a method like this ? Forgive me if I misunderstood.

Comment: @RoboLover: if he wants to query multiple columns AT THE SAME TIME, then the entire question is worded wrongly...

Comment: @TDaver I might have misunderstood, I am just asking the best way.

Comment: Still error on the last line (I use Linq2SQL). My sample is may be to easy, because I use inner join and in some case the field is part of th joined table

Comment: @Kris-I the sample works for the data presented. You don't say what the error *says*, nor do you provide an example that I can use to reproduce the error. I'm not psychic - kinda limited in what I can do without more context.

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact it is possible using the Expression API:

```
public void Searching(Expression<Func<User,string>> field, string stringToSearch)
{

   var call = Expression.Call(field.Body, typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains"), new[] {Expression.Constant(value)});
   Expression<Func<User, bool>> exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(Expression.Equal(call, Expression.Constant(true)), field.Parameters);


    var res =  _dataContext.USERs.Where(exp).Select(u=>new { id= u.ID, Username = u.USERNAME});

}
```

Comment: The projection (`Select`) *also* needs to be a custom expression

Comment: @MarcGravell: why? it is fully typed all the way!

Comment: "I'd like remplace `USERNAME` by the field name receive in parameter `field`" - hence `u.USERNAME` *does not exist*; it would be `u.SomethingElseHere`. I do like your use of the incoming expression for the base-body and the parameter, though!

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that part of the requirement :(

Comment: @Kris-I: there should be a `Body` member on `LambdaExpression`.

Comment: Heuuuu : Expression.Lambda Lambda unknow ? missing a namespace ?

Comment: @Kris-I: `using System.Linq.Expressions;`

Comment: @Kris-I: in that case `Expression` and `Expression.Lambda` should be there, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying is not possible. You can however use the [dynamic linq library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to achieve what you want

Comment: if we take away the anonymous type (maybe use a tuple instead), it *is* possible; indeed, if the dynamic LINQ library can do it, it MUST be possible; working on an example...

Comment: @MarcGravell waiting sample, others samples not working, compilation errors and others