# LINQ - Accessing a column with the column name as a string parameter

Tags: c#, sql, linq

(Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204817/use-string-as-field-name-in-linq))

I have tables called 'Questions' and 'FinalFigures':

Questions (QuestionID, Text, FinalFiguresColumnName)
FinalFigures (FinalFigureID, TotalDays, TotalCost, etc, etc)

'FinalFiguresColumnName' would have values like "TotalDays", "TotalCost", etc. Is there a simple way to loop through a set of Questions and have the 'Text' value saved to the corresponding column name on the 'FinalFigures' table?

Ie. instead of:

```
var item = new FinalFigure();
item.TotalDays = "x";
```

I need:

```
var item = new FinalFigure();
// access the column 'TotalDays' with its name as a string, not a property
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a bit of reflection to get the property value by the string name of the property instead of directly accessing it.

```
var value = (int)item.GetType().GetProperty("TotalDays").GetValue(item);
```

To set the value, simply call SetValue();

```
item.GetType().GetProperty("TotalDays").SetValue(item, value);
```